# How much energy is required to heat up a hot air balloon to make it neutrally buoyant?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-statics

To figure this out, I've tried to solve for $\Delta T$ for $PV=n_{cold}RT_{cold}$ and $PV=n_{warm}RT_{warm}$ which assumes that $PV$ is equal.  This gave me the equation: $$\Delta T = \frac{T_{cold}^2 \Delta m R}{PV m_m - T_{cold} \Delta m R}$$ Where:

- $\Delta m$ is the target mass (weight of the balloon) of air to displace in grams
- $m_m$ is the molar mass of air in g/mol
- $P$ is the pressure at the current elevation in Pa
- $V$ is the volume of the balloon in m³

However, looking at [Why is a hot air balloon  "stiff"?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7104/why-is-a-hot-air-balloon-stiff), I've come to realise that $P$ is not the same for each side of the balloon.

So my question is, am I correct that I'm wrong? If so, what can I do to correct this?

To be fair, I was considering that there was a support structure inside the balloon maintaining its shape, so maybe my assumption that $P$ is the same is valid?

The following is how I arrived at the formula if it is of interest:

\begin{array}{rl}
 \rm define                         & PV = n_c R T_c                                               & \tt (1a) \\
 \rm define                         & PV = n_w R T_w                                               & \tt (1b) \\
 \rm define                         & n_c = {m_c \over m_m}                                        & \tt (2a) \\
 \rm define                         & n_w = {m_w \over m_m}                                        & \tt (2b) \\
 \tt (2a)\Rightarrow(1a)            & PV = {m_c \over m_m} R T_c                                   & \tt (3a) \\
 \tt (2b)\Rightarrow(2b)            & PV = {m_w \over m_m} R T_w                                   & \tt (3b) \\
                                    & \Delta T = T_w - T_c                                         & \tt (4a) \\
 \rm isolate\ \it T_w\ \tt(4a)      & T_w = \Delta T + T_c                                         & \tt (4b) \\
 \tt (4b)\Rightarrow(3b)            & PV = {m_w \over m_m} R (\Delta T + T_c)                      & \tt (5)  \\
 \tt (5)\Rightarrow(3a)             & {m_w \over m_m} R (\Delta T + T_c) = {m_c \over m_m} R T_c   &          \\
                                    & m_w (\Delta T + T_c) = m_c T_c                               & \tt (6)  \\
 \rm isolate\ \it \Delta T\ \tt(6)  & m_w \Delta T + m_w T_c = m_c T_c                                        \\
                                    & m_w \Delta T = m_c T_c - m_w                                            \\
                                    & \Delta T = \frac{m_c T_c - m_w T_c} {m_w}                               \\
                                    & \Delta T = T_c \frac{m_c - m_w} {m_w}                        & \tt (7)  \\
 \rm define                         & \Delta m = m_c - m_w                                         & \tt (8)  \\
 \tt (8)\Rightarrow(7)              & \Delta T = T_c \frac{\Delta m} {m_w}                         & \tt (9)  \\
 \rm isolate\ \it m_w\ \tt (9)      & m_w = T_c \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta T}                          & \tt (10) \\
 \tt (10)\Rightarrow(3b)            & PV = {T_c \frac{\Delta m}{\Delta T} \over m_m} R T_w         &          \\
                                    & PV = \frac{T_c \Delta m R T_w}{\Delta T m_m}                 & \tt (11) \\
 \tt(4b)\Rightarrow(11)             & PV = \frac{T_c \Delta m R (\Delta T + T_c)}{\Delta T m_m}    & \tt (12) \\
 \rm isolate\ \it \Delta T\ \tt(12) & PV = \frac{T_c \Delta m R \Delta T + T_c \Delta m R T_c}{\Delta T m_m} \\
                                    & PV = \frac{T_c \Delta m R \Delta T}{\Delta T m_m} + \frac{T_c^2 \Delta m R}{\Delta T m_m} \\
                                    & PV = \frac{T_c \Delta m R}{m_m} + \frac{T_c^2 \Delta m R}{\Delta T m_m} \\
                                    & PV - \frac{T_c \Delta m R}{m_m} = \frac{T_c^2 \Delta m R}{\Delta T m_m} \\
                                    & \Delta T = \frac{T_c^2 \Delta m R}{\left(PV - \frac{T_c \Delta m R}{m_m}\right)m_m} \\
                                    & \Delta T = \frac{T_c^2 \Delta m R}{\frac{PV m_m - T_c \Delta m R}{m_m}m_m} \\
                                    & \Delta T = \frac{T_c^2 \Delta m R}{PV m_m - T_c \Delta m R} \\
\end{array}

Note that this is entirely based on Archimedes principle and is why I don't have any force equations listed, meaning that I'm assuming neutrally buoyant if I displace the weight of the balloon.  That's a valid approach, right?